# Any benefit to using default attribute when minOccurs attribrute is > 1?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-serialization

I came across a legacy XSD that has a bunch of lines like...

```
      <xs:element minOccurs="1"
                  maxOccurs="1"
                  default="true"
                  name="Ready" type="xs:boolean" />
```

...where minOccurs and maxOccurrs both equal 1, AND there is a default value.  Is there any benefit to having the default attribute here since the XML doc is required to contain some value any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/):

> The schema processor treats defaulted
>   elements slightly differently. When an
>   element is declared with a default
>   value, the value of the element is
>   whatever value appears as the
>   element's content in the instance
>   document; if the element appears
>   without any content, the schema
>   processor provides the element with a
>   value equal to that of the default
>   attribute. However, if the element
>   does not appear in the instance
>   document, the schema processor does
>   not provide the element at all. In
>   summary, the differences between
>   element and attribute defaults can be
>   stated as: Default attribute values
>   apply when attributes are missing, and
>   **default element values apply when elements are empty**.

I take this to mean that an empty `<Ready />` node would default to a value of TRUE based on your schema.