# Augment XML with XML Schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd, validation

javax.xml.validation.Validator has a [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html#validate%28javax.xml.transform.Source,%20javax.xml.transform.Result%29) to validate and augment xml against a schema.

Simplified xml:

```
<something>
  <sub1>false</sub1> <!-- Suppose sub1 is optional and may not be present in xml -->
  <sub2>false</sub2>
</something>
```

Simplified xsd:

```
<complexType name="something">
  <sequence>
    <element name="sub1" type="boolean" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" default="false"/>
    <element name="sub2" type="boolean" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Simplified validation and augmentation code:

```
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document document = builder.parse(new File(xmlFile));
DOMSource input = new DOMSource(document);
DOMResult output = new DOMResult();
validator.validate(input, output);

Document result = (Document)output.getNode();
```

So, besides validating xml against the schema, it should also augment it and add any missing defaults (like sub1) and send that into `output`.

However, `sub1` is not present in `result` when it is missing in xml.

Where am I off track here?

**EDIT:**

Ok, found the [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1750584/589008) why `sub1` is missing. But how can I ensure that `sub1` is present in `result` even when it's not in xml?

Comment: If it's optional and it's not present then why would you need to add the node?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884051/how-to-update-xml-file-from-another-xml-file-dynamically/9884503#9884503

Comment: It's supposed to be a config.xml and whenever elements are missing in xml, the augmented `Document` should just use the defaults from the xsd so the code doesn't have to bother with defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1750584/589008) quotes the spec: augmentation applies default values to empty elements. It does NOT add elements that are not present in xml.

In other words, augmentation by schema cannot guarantee that elements are present.